# Run-Time Error 1004 on Excel for renaming sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use this code in VBA to have the sheet rename themselves to the value of A1.
A1 is ='Enter Stats Here'!XX which corresponds to another sheet with all of the names.

This is the code I am currently using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("A1")
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Target, 31)
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I need the sheets to rename themselves based on the values in a different sheet

Comment: You are getting some sort of error then? What is your question?

Comment: The error comes up because the code is trying to give the same name to multiple sheets. Each sheet in a workbook must have a unique name. If you give more detail about what exactly is in `Range("A1")` someone can probably fix it.

Comment: It also seems odd you are using `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, then assigning `Set Target = Range("A1")`, instead of just using `Range("A1")` directly... Do you want this macro to run every time you click a new cell? How many sheets do you have this macro in / how many sheets do you want to rename?

Comment: I have 20 Sheets that are trying to use this Macro. I do want it to run everytime so that when theres a change that needs to be made, it automatically updates. A1 is An ='Enter stats here'!A1 and hten sheet 2 is A2 etc... I'm very new to VBA so im recycling the code from another sheet that does something similar. It was also working for a little bit and then all of a sudden I get the run time 1004 error

Comment: Are the values in "Enter stats here" being updated manually?

Comment: Yes they will be updated manually there.

Comment: On 'Enter stats here'!A1, A2, A3, etc. - do you have different names in all those cells, or are there any duplicates? And for the sheet that is giving you the error - let's say you get the error on Sheet2 - what is the name on 'Enter stats here'! that corresponds to Sheet2? Is there another sheet in the workbook that already has the same name?

Comment: They will have different names because they will be different agents. There is no other sheet that has the same name. All of the sheets that use this code are having the same problem.